# Issue with reversing list using list.pop()

Tags: python, loops, stack, reverse

I was working on writing a small code snippet to reverse a string using list appends and pop.

The script that I wrote is as follows:

```
someStr = raw_input("Enter some string here:")
strList = []
for c in someStr:
    strList.append(c)

print strList

reverseCharList = []
for someChar in strList:
    reverseCharList.append(strList.pop())

print reverseCharList
```

When I enter a string abcd, the output that's returned is [d,c].

I know I am mutating the list I am iterating over but can somebody explain why the chars 'a' and 'b' is not displayed here?

Thanks

Comment: This is a great exercise to learn recursion!

Comment: Just to make sure: you do know about `[].reverse()`, right?

Comment: @Nathon - Yes I do. I just wanted to know the reason for the discrepancy in the output.

Comment: "I know I am mutating the list I am iterating over but..." Have you heard the story about the guy who went to the doctor and said "Doctor, it hurts when I do this" and the doctor replies "Well then, don't do that!" :) Seriously though I'm glad you got your question answered.

Comment: The point of this exercise was to figure out "why" it hurts when "that" is done. And the good Doctors of SO did explain the "why".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about a simple reversal of string.

```
>>> x = 'abcd'
>>> x[::-1]
'dcba'
>>>
```

On your code:

> Never mutate the list on which you are iterating with. It can cause subtle errors.

```
>>> strList = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> reverseCharList = []
>>> for someChar in strList:
...     print strList
...     reverseCharList.append(strList.pop())
...     print strList
... 
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]   <-- Iteration 1
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 4]      <-- Iteration 2
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3]         <-- Iteration 3
[1, 2]
```

See the following. Since you are using iterator (for .. in ..).
You can see the iterator details directly and how mutating the list messes up with iterator.

```
>>> strList = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> k = strList.__iter__()
>>> k.next()
1
>>> k.__length_hint__()   <--- Still 4 to go
4
>>> strList.pop()         <---- You pop an element
5
>>> k.__length_hint__()   <----- Now only 3 to go
3
>>> 
>>> k.next()
2
>>> k.__length_hint__()
2
```

Comment: Thanks for the alternate version. I just wanted to know what is wrong with the snippet that I posted.

Comment: ''.join(reversed('abcd')) also does the same thing, but according to timeit doing it with list slicing operator is about 9 times faster!

Answer (score 5):

```
for someChar in strList:
    reverseCharList.append(strList.pop())
```

Is essentially the same as:

```
i = 0
while i < len(strList):
    reverseCharList.append(strList.pop())
    i += 1
```

First iteration i is 0, len(strList) is 4, and you pop+append 'd'.

Second iteration i is 1, len(strList) is 3, and you pop+append 'c'.

Third iteration i is 2, len(strList) is 2, so the loop condition fails and you're done.

(This is really done with an iterator on the list, not a local variable 'i'. I've shown it this way for clarity.)

If you want to manipulate the sequence you're iterating over it's generally better to use a while loop. eg:

```
while strList:
    reverseCharList.append(strList.pop())
```

Comment: This is a great explanation. Is there someplace that I can look at for the specifics on how the for-in constructor is implemented in Python using iterators?

Comment: @sc_ray : I have included a simple illustration of effect of iterator on changing sequence.

Answer (score 1):

You shorten the list when you pop.

```
reverseCharList = []
while strList:
    reverseCharList.append(strList.pop())
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple recersive version:

```
def reverse(the_list):
    if not the_list:
        return []
    return [the_list.pop()] + reverse(the_list)
```

Of course, `[].reverse()` is faster.